# Obtener substring de una lista de elementros

Tags: python, regex

dada la siguiente lista

```
list = [
'5 5/8 x 8 1/2 in. (14.29 x 21.59 cm)',
'8 9/16 x 5 1/2 in. (21.75 x 13.97 cm) (sheet) 16 1/4 x 10 in. (41.28 x 25.4 cm) (mount)',
'8 3/16 x 13 9/16 in. (20.8 x 34.45 cm) (sheet)',
'7 5/16 x 12 3/8 in. (18.57 x 31.43 cm) (sight) 14 1/4 x 18 3/4 x 7/16 in. (36.2 x 47.63 x 1.11 cm) (outer frame)',
'1 1/2 x 3/4 x 1/2 in. (3.81 x 1.91 x 1.27 cm)',
'7 9/16 x 9 1/2 in. (19.21 x 24.13 cm) (image) 13 x 15 in. (33.02 x 38.1 cm) (mount)',
'7 32 x 43533x 44 cm'
]
```

Necesito obtener los valores de los centímetros, pero no logro encontrar una solución que sirva para todo dado que no existe un patrón. Lo único común entre todo es cm, pero luego los tamaños cambian y no siempre están entre paréntesis.

Estoy intentando usar regex print(re.search('((.+?)cm', record).group(1)) pero no considera el ultimo caso.

Comment: ¿Y que es lo que quieres capturar?¿El número antes de `cm`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este patrón reconoce las dimensiones en cms:

```
(?:\s|\()([\.\d]+)\s*(x|cm)
```

El patrón pide algo que:

- `\s|\(` Empiece con espacio o abre paréntesis.
- `[\.\d]+` Un valor decimal.
- `\s*` Cero o más espacios.
- `x|cm` Terminados en `x` o `cm`.

El prefijo `?:` señala que se descarta esa parte del texto reconocido.

Usando `findall()`, obtenemos listas de tuplas en el siguiente formato:

```
[('21.75', 'x'), ('13.97', 'cm'), ('41.28', 'x'), ('25.4', 'cm')]
```

Y hay que agregar código para extraer los valores usando `cm` como delimitador de un conjunto de valores.

#### Demo

```
import re

lista = [
'5 5/8 x 8 1/2 in. (14.29 x 21.59 cm)',
'8 9/16 x 5 1/2 in. (21.75 x 13.97 cm) (sheet) 16 1/4 x 10 in. (41.28 x 25.4 cm) (mount)',
'8 3/16 x 13 9/16 in. (20.8 x 34.45 cm) (sheet)',
'7 5/16 x 12 3/8 in. (18.57 x 31.43 cm) (sight) 14 1/4 x 18 3/4 x 7/16 in. (36.2 x 47.63 x 1.11 cm) (outer frame)',
'1 1/2 x 3/4 x 1/2 in. (3.81 x 1.91 x 1.27 cm)',
'7 9/16 x 9 1/2 in. (19.21 x 24.13 cm) (image) 13 x 15 in. (33.02 x 38.1 cm) (mount)',
'7 32 x 43533x 44 cm',
'5 5/8 x 8 1/2 in.'
]

patron = re.compile(r"(?:\s|\()([\.\d]+)\s*(x|cm)")

for item in lista:
    m = patron.findall(item)
    if m:
        print(f"De {item} se extrajo:")
        medida = []
        for valor, caracter in m:
            medida.append(valor)
           if caracter == 'cm':
               print(f"  {medida}")
               medida = []
```

produce:

```
De 5 5/8 x 8 1/2 in. (14.29 x 21.59 cm) se extrajo:
  ['14.29', '21.59']
De 8 9/16 x 5 1/2 in. (21.75 x 13.97 cm) (sheet) 16 1/4 x 10 in. (41.28 x 25.4 cm) (mount) se extrajo:
  ['21.75', '13.97']
  ['41.28', '25.4']
De 8 3/16 x 13 9/16 in. (20.8 x 34.45 cm) (sheet) se extrajo:
  ['20.8', '34.45']
De 7 5/16 x 12 3/8 in. (18.57 x 31.43 cm) (sight) 14 1/4 x 18 3/4 x 7/16 in. (36.2 x 47.63 x 1.11 cm) (outer frame) se extrajo:
  ['18.57', '31.43']
  ['36.2', '47.63', '1.11']
De 1 1/2 x 3/4 x 1/2 in. (3.81 x 1.91 x 1.27 cm) se extrajo:
  ['3.81', '1.91', '1.27']
De 7 9/16 x 9 1/2 in. (19.21 x 24.13 cm) (image) 13 x 15 in. (33.02 x 38.1 cm) (mount) se extrajo:
  ['19.21', '24.13']
  ['13', '33.02', '38.1']
De 7 32 x 43533x 44 cm se extrajo:
  ['32', '43533', '44']

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Resueltisimo muchas gracias.